# Script Tag error

Tags: api, shopify

I have read about http://api.shopify.com/scripttag.html documentation and when i'm try to inject javascript into my shopify apps store using script_tag, i found error message "[API] You do not have script_tags write permissions". 
How to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps are either read-write or read-only.  It sounds like you have a read-only application and read-only apps are unable to create script tags.  You'll need to either create a new app that is read-write (i.e. if you're still just doing development) or contact the Shopify folks about potentially switching the app to read-write.

Comment: Note that this is only the case if you’re using the older legacy auth.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using [OAuth2 Authentication](http://api.shopify.com/authentication.html), then you need the write_script_tags scope.  The [list of scopes](http://api.shopify.com/authentication.html#scopes) is on the Authentication page in the api documentation.

If you are using the [Legacy Authentication](http://api.shopify.com/legacy_authentication.html), then you need to have an app with write access, as scotchi mentions.